# <li value="${livre.titre}"> throws java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "titre"

Tags: jsp, servlets, el

I have a 500 error and the stacktrace is showing me a number format error, but all my variables are string, so I don't see at all where the error is.

In addition, my JDBC connection is good because in debug mode I get to see my value from the database, but once it goes in the JSP it does not work anymore.

Can someone help me out? Here is my code:

My servlet :

```
package com.octest.servlets;
import java.io.IOException;

import bdd.LivresBDD;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import model.Livres;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class test
 */

public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public test() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        LivresBDD tableLivres = new LivresBDD();
        request.setAttribute("livre", tableLivres.recupererLivres());
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/bonjour.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Livres livre = new Livres();
        livre.setTitre(request.getParameter("titre"));
        livre.setAuteur(request.getParameter("auteur"));
        livre.setGenre(request.getParameter("genre"));
       
       LivresBDD tableLivres = new LivresBDD();
       tableLivres.ajouterLivres(livre);
       
       request.setAttribute("livre", tableLivres.recupererLivres());
       
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/bonjour.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

My jsp file:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%@ include file="menu.jsp" %>
        <p>Bonjour à vous !</p>
        <p>
        <ul>
        <li value="${livre.titre}"></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

My bean:

```
package model;

public class Livres {
    private String titre;
    private String auteur;
    private String genre;
    

    
    public String getTitre() {
        return titre;
    }
    
    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        this.titre = titre;
    }
    public String getAuteur() {
        return auteur;
    }
    
    public void setAuteur(String auteur) {
        this.auteur = auteur;
    }
    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }
    
    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }
}
```

My database connection :

```
package bdd;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.Livres;

public class LivresBDD {


    private Connection connexion;
    
    public List<Livres> recupererLivres() {
        List<Livres> livres = new ArrayList<Livres>();
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultat = null;

        loadDatabase();
        
        try {
            statement = connexion.createStatement();

            // Exécution de la requête
            resultat = statement.executeQuery("SELECT titre, auteur, genre FROM livres;");

            // Récupération des données
            while (resultat.next()) {
                String titre = resultat.getString("titre");
                String auteur = resultat.getString("auteur");
                String genre = resultat.getString("genre");
                
                Livres livre = new Livres();
                livre.setTitre(titre);
                livre.setAuteur(auteur);
                livre.setGenre(genre);
                
                livres.add(livre);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        } finally {
            // Fermeture de la connexion
            try {
                if (resultat != null)
                    resultat.close();
                if (statement != null)
                    statement.close();
                if (connexion != null)
                    connexion.close();
            } catch (SQLException ignore) {
            }
        }
        
        return livres;
    }
    
    private void loadDatabase() {
        // Chargement du driver
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        }

        try {
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bibliotheque", "root", "");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void ajouterLivres(Livres livre) {
        loadDatabase();
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connexion.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO livres(titre,auteur,genre) VALUES(?, ?, ?);");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, livre.getTitre());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, livre.getAuteur());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, livre.getGenre());
            
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my stacktrace :

```
État HTTP 500 – Erreur interne du serveur
Type Rapport d'exception
message Une exception s'est produite lors du traitement de [WEB-INF/bonjour.jsp] à la ligne [13]
description Le serveur a rencontré une erreur interne qui l'a empêché de satisfaire la requête.
exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Une exception s'est produite lors du traitement de [WEB-INF/bonjour.jsp] à la ligne [13]

10:         <p>Bonjour Ã  vous !</p>
11:         <p>
12:         <ul>
13:         <li value="${livre.titre}"></li>
14:         </ul>
15:     </body>
16: </html>

Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:611)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    com.octest.servlets.test.doGet(test.java:32)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
cause mère
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "titre"
java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    jakarta.el.ListELResolver.coerce(ListELResolver.java:150)
    jakarta.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:67)
org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:125)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:190)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:709)
org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.bonjour_jsp._jspService(bonjour_jsp.java:141)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:71)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:467)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    com.octest.servlets.test.doGet(test.java:32)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:663)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
note La trace complète de la cause mère de cette erreur est disponible dans les fichiers journaux de ce serveur.
Apache Tomcat/10.0.4
```

Comment: The `<li value=...` attribute expects a number and so it (the http servlet parser) attempts to parse `${livre.titre}` as a number and throws a parse exception because evidently it is set to 'titre'..The `value` attribute is only applicable for `ol` btw.

Comment: Even with an ol tag the server returns me a 500 error. The same goes for a p tag :(

Comment: The `ol` comment is a footnote to the main issue - it expects a number and you are giving it a string which cannot be parsed as a number.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error because you are sending a collection of books to the JSP file, but you are trying to use it like it's a single book.

In your servlet, you are doing:

```
request.setAttribute("livre", tableLivres.recupererLivres());
```

The `tableLivres.recupererLivres()` method returns a `List<Livres>`. This is a collection of books, not a single book. But in your JSP you are treating this collection as a single book and doing `${livre.titre}`.

By the way, you should really clear up this mess of singular and plural `Livre`. Your class should be called `Livre` not `Livres`, because it's just one book. And when you send the collection to the JSP it should be called `livres` because there are more, like this:

```
request.setAttribute("livres", tableLivres.recupererLivres());
```

Once you have done that, then in the JSP you need to treat the data as a list. In your code you are treating it as one book and the [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) expression engine probably tries to use the `titre` property to index the list and from here your `NumberFormatException`. Handle the data in the JSP as what it is: a list. [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) can help loop the list. Add it to your project if you don't already have it, then in your JSP loop through the list like so:

```
<ul>
  <c:forEach items="${livres}" var="unLivre">
    <li>
      <c:out value="${unLivre.titre}" />
    </li>
  </c:forEach>        
</ul>
```

Notice that I changed the attribute name to `livres` as it should be named for what you are doing.